# Cannot reach resource through ingress on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, devops, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to create an Ingress resource that fans out to two services that are running healthily. This is my very simple config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: service1
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /service2/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service2
              servicePort: 9090
```

Only requests to the root (`/`) path seem to work. I've been trying to trouble shoot this using similar posts online, but nothing has worked for me.

What can I do?

#### Edit:

This config works fine on Minikube, but doesn't on GKE?

Comment: What do you get on `service2`? 404?

Comment: Yes, I get a `404` on `service2`.

Comment: Do you have actually anything serving on path `/service2` of your backend?

Comment: 404 implies the request is reaching the backend, there is just nothing there. If you check the logs on one of the backends for service2, you should see the requests come in along with the error and that should help you debug this further

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default ingress controller of GKE, then the `yaml` looks good to me. I will suggest you, to recheck the services (i.e. service1, service2) of **NodePort** type and make sure that they are working fine.

In case you're using the [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/) of the version above or equal to `nginx-0.20.0`, you need to set the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex` annotation to `true` (the default is `false`) to **enable** the case sensitive regular expression.

Just like:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: service1
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /service2/*
            backend:
              serviceName: service2
              servicePort: 9090
```

Comment: Thank you!

This seems to work on Minikube, but I'm still having issues on GKE.

By changing my services to kind `NodePort` from `LoadBalancer`, I can now access the resources on my Minikube cluster. 

However, I am now getting `default backend - 404` when trying to access `service2` through my GKE cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working configuration on Azure, it's very simple yet differs from yours in a few ways. I rewrote your yaml accordingly, see if that helps:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /service2/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: service2
              servicePort: 9090
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: service1
              servicePort: 8080
```

The notable differences are:

1. Paths are flipped so that the more specific one is higher up. Not sure if that has any influence.
2. Changed the simple wildcard to a look-ahead: `*` => `?(.*)`. This allows me to use the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation to make sure that I don't lose the part of the url that follows `/service2/`. So if you were calling anything *but* /service2/ exactly, this might help.

Comment: Interesting. This works exactly as my config does on Minikube, but on GKE I get this error:

```
Error during sync: error running load balancer syncing routine: loadbalancer default-my-ingress--cbc24f100656b420 does not exist: CreateUrlMap: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value for field 'resource': '{ "name": "k8s-um-default-my-ingress--cbc24f100656b420", "hostRule": [{ "host": ["*"], ...'. Invalid path pattern, invalid
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"` to *this* configuration, as suggested before?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **nginx**, please check-out this [github issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1120#issuecomment-322007251).

If you are using **traefik** try:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  name: my-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: service1
      - path: /service2/
        backend:
          serviceName: service2
```